# Running GWTTestCase with Maven

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am not able to make GWT Test run with my GWT Library project when running $mvn clean install it throws this error:

```
[ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

However the app have that in the `App.gwt.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
  <inherits name="org.restlet.Restlet" />
  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

And the Test code is very simple:

```
public class AppTest extends GWTTestCase {
    @Before
    public void prepareTests(){

    }
    @After
    public void afterTests() {

    }
    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "com.mycompany.App";
    }
    @Test
    public void test(){
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

What could be the problem that prevents the test from running?

Comment: How are you launching your tests? surefire/failsafe? with which config? gwt:test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.- Don't use Junit-4 but Junit-3, remove `@Test` and name your tests with the `test` prefix

2.- Override getModuleName returning your gwt module

3.- Use `gwtSetup` and `gwtTearDown` instead of `@Before` and `@After`

```
  public class MyGwtTest extends GWTTestCase {

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
      return "com.example.MyApp";
    }
    @Override
    protected void gwtSetUp() throws Exception {
    }
    @Override
    protected void gwtTearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    public void testSomething() {
      // test something
    }
  }
```

4.- Configure gwt-maven appropriatelly so as you can use `mvn gwt:test` to run your tests

5.- Or configure your maven project with this surefire configuration, and you can use the normal way `mvn test`.

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <additionalClasspathElements>
       <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
       <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
     </additionalClasspathElements>
     <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
     <forkMode>always</forkMode>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting Exception in thread "htmlUnit client thread" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Comment: I fixed it by adding the google-http-client dependency

Comment: Thanks for answering its been my problem since the new year :-)